# Can't parse text to Decimal

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In Form_load I have

```
txtAlteFonduri.Text = "5,00";
txtFReparatii.Text = "15,00";
txtFRulment.Text = "20,00";
```

and in another function I want to parse text as decimal

```
decimal alteFonduri = Decimal.Parse(txtAlteFonduri.Text);
decimal fondRulment = Decimal.Parse(txtFRulment.Text);
decimal fondRepar = Decimal.Parse(txtFReparatii.Text);
```

but I have an error in the second line

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you're already getting the error for the first line :-)

Comment: no it works only for first line in form_load. if I change txtAlteFonduri with anothe line that will be work in function and anothe no

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specifically add the number format. For your examples above, the following should work:

```
decimal alteFonduri = Decimal.Parse(txtAlteFonduri.Text, CultureInfo.GetCulture("de-DE"));
```

Otherwise, the system's culture information is used.

Comment: in add, you can set globalization in config file, like <globalization culture="de-DE"/>, into <system.web> tag

Comment: Unless you are creating a Windows Forms application, as the tags say he's doing. Then, there is no `web.config` and no `<system.web>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a different culture to what decimal.Parse() is expecting (it expects the decimal point '.' but you provide a comma. Using the correct culture should correctly parse the strings, although I can run your code without having any errors...

You can use Decimal.Parse(variable, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("Culture-Name"));

Comment: Different regions, different settings, right? That's the fun about I18n.

Comment: Yeah, running the OP's code just ignored the commas for me, causing the numbers to be 100x bigger than intended :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [this overload of `Decimal.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7xswkc6.aspx) and supply a [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) matching the culture of your input. You should also consider using one of the [`Decimal.TryParse` methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3b1e5ha.aspx) for better error handling.